# How can I connect between containers?

Tags: python, docker, sockets, docker-compose

I want client socket can enter the server socket via `localhost:8080`,
but I keep getting this error message 
:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

This is my server socket

```
import socket
import threading   

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 8080
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))


serverSocket.listen(1)

connectionSocket, address = serverSocket.accept()
print('*****',str(address), 'has entered.*****')
```

and `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "serversocket.py"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

This is client socket

```
import socket
import threading

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverPort = 8080
clientSocket.connect(('localhost', serverPort))


print('*****You Enter the server.*****')
```

and `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "clientsocket.py"]
```

and finally is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3"

services: 
  server:
    image: server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"


  client:
    image: client
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `clientSocket.connect(('server', serverPort))` ?

Comment: I use option 'docker run -p 8080:8080' to access server socket via localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Your server **and** your client run in a Docker network. The fact that you open the server port 8080 is only relevant for your local machine.

In the context of the client container, `localhost` is not your local machine, it's its own "local network". So, trying to connect to `localhost:8080` won't work from the local container.

What's nice with `docker-compose` is that it implicitly creates a common Docker network and bind it to each containers defined. Thus, inside a container, you can reach its fellow containers **by their name**.

You can try it if you run a shell session from inside the container:

```sh
docker-compose exec client sh # Opens a prompt INSIDE the client container
ping server # Ping the hostname server. It will respond.
```

So, let's go back to your issue. You should do this in your client code:

```py
 # The hostname is the name of the container, "server"
clientSocket.connect(('server', serverPort))
```

As a side note, it would be better if the server hostname and the port are defined as environment variables. It will allow you to easily change those values (for example, in the `docker-compose` file) without having to rebuild the image.